# React bootstrap Form.Control onClick callback is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Here iam mapping the array and displaying options.

```
 <Form.Control as="select">
   {category.specifications.map(cat => {
     return <option key={cat._id} onClick={()=>handleClick(cat)}>{cat.category}</option>
     })
    }
</Form.Control>
```

so when i click an option it should trigger handle click function. but it isn't working. I dont know what is wrong in this.

```
  const handleClick = (id) => {
        console.log(id)
        console.log('id')
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I need this too to highlight the field onClick as a separate event to onChange. onClick={() => {console.log('clicked');}} works for me alothough the IDE complains but it still works

Answer (score 1):

There is no onClick method in React Bootstrap Form Control. You can use it's onChange method like

```
<Form.Control as="select" onChange={this.handleChange}>
   {category.specifications.map(cat => {
     return <option value={cat._id}>{cat.category}</option>
     })
    }
</Form.Control>


handleChange = (event) => {
    let cat_id = event.target.value; <-- This will give you selected cat id -->
}
```

Comment: yeah i get it. but i want the the cat._id to be passed to handleChange function. how to achieve that?

Comment: I have updated my answer. In that way, you can have cat_id of the selected option item

Answer (score 1):

In order to use cat._id i have to set an attribute called value like this

```
<Form.Control as="select" onChange={this.handleChange}>
   {category.specifications.map(cat => {
     return <option value={cat_id} >{cat.category}</option>
     })
    }
</Form.Control>
```

now i can use that value in a function

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    const catId = event.target.value
}
```